# Android service startforeground LocationManager requestLocationUpdates when device is sleeping

Tags: android, service, gps, foreground

I have a service that is running as a foreground service

```
startForeground(1234, notification);
```

In this service I have a runnable that should run every 15 minutes :

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Log.d("maw", "Gps::run");
        if (Constants.checkInternet(getApplicationContext())) checkSheet();
        handler.postDelayed(this, Constants.REFRESH_TIME);
    }
};
```

When the device is connected to the internt it executes the method checkSheet().
This method checks some stuff with a server, and depending on the result it starts up the GPS and track the location of the device.

```
locationMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, GPS_TIME, GPS_DISTANCE, this);
```

Now... In our tests this all seems working fine. But the users have problems, in that sometimes they only see the trace hours after it should have started logging.

Now the question is what the reason is behind this.
I am guessing they don't use their devices as much as our devices and the devices are going into a sleeping mode our test devices never enter because we use the devices more frequently

Some questions :
For a foreground service :
- Does the Runnable stop running every 15 minutes when the device goes to some deeper sleep mode ?
- Is it not possible to initialize a locationManager.requestLocationUpdates when the device is in some deeper sleep mode ?

Comment: Why not using wake lock?
[PowerManager.WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html)

Comment: you should accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), so your service only needs to be in memory when it is actually doing work.
Or you can use [wakelock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html).

Comment: The service actually is working almost all the time. Every 15 minutes the service does stuff.

Checking if GPS should get enabled, and enable it is just 1 thing.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing it seemed that the runnable sometimes crashed and completely stopped working.

After fixing that issue now it seems that for a foreground service the Runnable does keep running, and the locationManager.requestLocationUpdates does do what it should do.